# Forcing Lowercase URL Parameters in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am developing an app in Rails 3.2 that uses the `to_params` to change the URL/route to a custom one.

The `to_params` in the model is something like this:

```
def to_params
  keyword
end
```

Then, in the controllers, I look up the object using:

```
def show
  @object = Object.find_by_keyword(params[:id])
end
```

I also have a `before_save` in the model that ensures all `keyword` entries are lowercase, so the URLs come out like http://mydomain.com/object/keyword.

My question is... Some users might be tempted to capitalize a keyword or something when putting it in the URL themselves. How can I convert that URL into lowercase before trying to find the object in the controller? I've tried `@object = Object.find_by_keyword(params[:id].lowercase)`, but it didn't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does your model is called "Object" or is it just example? Ruby already has "Object" class, which is superclass of almost all other objects in Ruby, so this could be misleading.

Comment: -1 for missing examples of values or more details which would help solve problem.

Comment: Ok, what other details do you need? I'm still searching for an answer to the question. If I could -1 a comment, I would to yours for not specifying what details you want!?

Comment: Are you sure it is a String object (log its #class attribute), are you sure it doesn't have any whitespaces around (log ">>#{params[:id]}<<")? Do you have any filters around that action? Could you provide fragment of logs where you hit that action with params listed? Is your #find_by_keyrord standard method_missing magic, or you coded it in model? What specific values doesn't work in controller and works in console? Remember - It's your problem, we're here to try to help you, but we can't if we don't have enough informations and you go away for 2 weeks from your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@object = Object.find_by_keyword(params[:id].downcase)`

Should work

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've already tried this (as stated in my question), but it's not working. The object isn't returned and the page erred out after the first @object call.

Comment: Well you were using `lowercase`. The method in ruby is `downcase`.

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize that I said `lowercase` above! Long day... But I meant `downcase`, tried that, and it wasn't working. Same error with the first object call being nil.

Comment: @Justin Are you absolutely sure that you have what you think in `params[:id]`? Could you post some logs for us from requests with lowercase keyword and then uppercase?

Comment: @Justin Also - can you confirm that your `find_by_keyword` returns correct results in `rails console`?

Comment: I know that `params[:id]` and `find_by_keyword` work, since they function with the lowercase value. I'm simply trying to convert uppercase to lowercase if a user decides to use uppercase in the URL.

Comment: You should really log somewhere values of both `params[:id]` and `params[:id].downcase`. Then query for the content of `params[:id].downcase` in `rails console`

Comment: The downcase function works properly and the upcase function works properly. `find_by_keyword` returns the correct thing, since again, it works properly with the non-modified version. I tried the query and it works properly separately, but not when it's in the `find_by_keyword` param it seems.